# Why HTTP 400 is facing when uploading file on live hosting server?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

When I upload file on web hosting server, then customize url is not working. Below is the code:
.httacces

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^product/single/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)$ single?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<a href="product/single/<?php echo $rowa['id']; ?>/<?php echo preg_replace('/[]^\p{N}\s]/u', '-', $rowa['name']); ?>">
<img src="admin/assets/product_image/<?php echo $rowa['product_image']; ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive img_div_2" style="height:200px; width:80%;" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, could you please do explain more what's not working. Just mention what **link** you are hitting and what is not working in it? Eg: URL change in browser **or** url rewriting in backend file etc.

Comment: Above url is working on  localhost but when we put that on live server  then 404 page is not found is displayed. What can I change in .htaccess file that can url can work on live server

Comment: did you tried restarting server on live?? if it's apache on linux then sudo service apache2 restart. and you may need to run sudo a2enmod as well

Comment: I am using cpanel

Comment: Could you please add a specific URL that is requested and that results into a 404 add to the question? Not just how they get created? Thanks.

Comment: Please, help me by providing a better solution of my problem?